# Transfer NFT if account lost

Tags: nft

I'm a newbie in NFT, ETH and I have a question.

Can I transfer NFT if the account was compromised?

More precisely, I mean two situations for example:

1. If I author of Digital Art and I sold it. I will get a royalty when the next buyer sells it too. How can I'm to save royalty if my account was compromised? How I understand compromised account write down in a smart contract. Is it possible to change it?
2. If I just buy NFT, I'm not the author. How can I save my assets and transfer them to a new account if my old account was compromised?